# Removing the last item in a listbox? vb 2008

Tags: vb.net, text, listbox, line

I have a simple question. I have a listbox called listbox1. I want to add a button that removes the last item on the bottom whatever it maybe, when the button is clicked.

But I don't know how to finish it. something simple like listbox1.removeitem(some number?)

What could I add to remove whatever item that is on the bottom on the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will remove the last item in your ListBox. [Using the RemoveAt method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.removeat.aspx).

```
ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1)
```

Using the RemoveAt method, we remove the item at the Index provided. Since we get the full length of items in your current ListBox (and subtract 1 because it is zero based) we get the last item.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [RemoveAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.removeat.aspx) method and get the last element by it's `count - 1` since it's zero based array.

```
Listbox1.Items.RemoveAt(Listbox1.Items.Count - 1)
```